# How to locate a block that is used by Magento, but isn't displayed in the admin panel?

Tags: magento

I've inherited a Magento shop site, and the previous developer has gone AWOL. So I'm left with a sheet of paper essentially telling me how to do basic things such as changing the banner on the home page. That's pretty much it.

The person who owns the page now wants to change an advert that's held on the right hand side on the product pages. I've searched in the Admin panel under CMS and drawn a blank. I've navigated through the template files and I've found the 3 column HTML file that I thought contains the actual advert.

It doesn't. Instead, it has the following code:

```
<div class="col-right sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?></div>
```

Where can I find the Child HTML? I've searched all of the folders for the file that I'm assuming is called "Right". But I can't seem to find it.

Anyone know where something like this could or would be held?

Answer (score 1):

That is the absolute most root function, anything that is placed in the child "right" will be displayed here and is most certainly not where you want to be doing your editing.

There are literally a hundred different ways content could be posted here and what I would recommend to start with is first determining if it is a static block or a template file.

1. Go to System -> Configuration -> Developer.
2. Change "Current Configuration Scope:" to the store you are currently troubleshooting.
3. Find your IP and place it in "Allowed IPs (comma separated)", this way the next steps will only be visible to you.
4. Under the "Debug" section you should now see "Template Path Hints" enable this and reload the page.

If that block now has something like: "app/design/base/default/catalog/product/view.phtml" you know it is in a phtml file and you can go there.  If it doesn't:

1. It could be a banner, go to CMS -> Banners and check there.
2. It could be a static block, go to CMS -> Static Blocks
3. It could be...any number of things.

You stated that it is on the product page, next step is check catalog.xml in your layout folders.  Search for  and see if anything inside of there makes sense about what it could be.  If the previous developer was any kind of proficient it won't be in catalog.xml but in local.xml OR a custom module's .xml file in the layout directory of the custom theme.

Try doing a search on the code base for the content inside of the block and see if anything pops up.  If nothing, use phpmyadmin to search the database for some of the content.

Hope this helps a little.

Answer (score -1):

Search for:

```
<reference name="right">
```